# An explicit bijection between the power set $\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$ and $2^\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know how to show that these two have the same cardinality and from that there must be a bijection between them.

Can anyone help with an explicit bijection between these sets?

Comment: $\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$ and $2^\mathbb{N}$ both denote the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Usually $2^X$ denotes the set of functions $X \to 2$, which is naturally isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (in classical logic anyway...) but is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Think about, given $E\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, the indicator function $\chi_E:\mathbb{N}\to 2$ given by $\chi_E(n)=1$ if $n\in E$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Consider [indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) (or characteristic) functions of subsets of $\Bbb N$.